# Who has the highest yearly, non-stock, cash-only-considered salary in modern history?

Tags: contemporary-history

When we consider the world’s wealthiest in history, we use accrual accounting and thinking, considering broad spectrum of assets and instruments. Let us disconsider this.

Historically: Who is the 20th-21st century’s wealthiest in terms of how much unadulterated cash, nothing else, they receive in their banking account or wallet every year for their personal use? Again, no stocks or stock options, just cash.

Comment: Are you accounting for inflation or not?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that [Pablo Escobar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pablo_Escobar) probably tops the cash-only list.

> Pablo was earning so much that each year we would write off 10% of the money because the rats would eat it in storage or it would be damaged by water or lost
>
> [Business Insider Article](http://uk.businessinsider.com/pablo-escobar-and-rubber-bands-2015-9)

[image: lots of cash]

Comment: That's not exactly a "Salary" though. Closer to a dividend.

Comment: Part of the problem is always going to be defining what actually counts as a "salary" because that's going to vary by tax domain.

Comment: Does drug money count as "unadulterated" cash? ;)

Comment: Yeah, after rereading the question, I'm starting to like this answer more. If OQ is honest about mostly wanting to know who rakes in the most cash, the answer almost *has* to be a drug kingpin. They actually have the problem that they earn **too much** cash, and have trouble converting it into more useful long-term assets. Someone like Bill Gates has the opposite problem, that all his wealth is in one long-term security, and he can't exactly liquidate it all tomorrow without devaluing it (and thus losing tons of his wealth) in the process.

Comment: T.E.D. - You mean that MOST, not ALL, of  Bill Gate's wealth is in one long-term security.  Surely his company pays him a salary and his  stock pays dividends, and he uses that income for living expenses, to buy perishable goods, and to invest in other stocks, bonds, etc.  I'm sure Gates owns expensive real estate, automobiles, private jets, etc., which also have potential sale value.  You mean that MOST, not ALL, of his wealth is in a single investment.

Comment: I wouldn't say "surely".  Steve Jobs' salary was famously $1.  For a major stockholder who is also a CEO, "salary" is often an insignificant part of their wealth.  Another exactly is Warren Buffet, whose earnings is in the billions, but whose salary is only $100,000 per year.

Comment: @MAGolding - He's retired. Considering his relative Forbes ranking goes [up and down with the value of Microsoft stock](https://www.forbes.com/2008/03/05/buffett-worlds-richest-cx_mm_0229buffetrichest.html#713bea833180), and presumably largely came with its phenomenal share price growth over the last 40 years (rather than any salary he drew), its probably fair to consider the amount *not* tied up in that to be negligible. Relatively. I'm sure everyone reading this would happily agree to live the rest of their lives off of that "negligible" amount.